# Define the methods of anonimous class created inside a method from the method caller

Tags: java, anonymous-class

in a class i have

```
A a = new A(){
    stuffhere
};
```

now i found that i need to create the new A inside a method and return it, but i have to define the stuffhere from the class caller. Is there a way in java to do so? Something like

```
A a = createAClass(){
       stuffhere
};

public A createAClass()[T]{
       return new A(){T};
}
```

or something similar. I would prefer not to use an interface to pass to the create method, since my anonymous classes not only override methods, but also adds attributes and new functions, and i don't think i can pass them with an interface..

Any thought?

**EDIT** for the -1ers (a simple comment would suffice)
with the syntax [T], obviously wrong, i meant something that can pass a generic code, let's say a copy-paste of code.

```
createAClass()[int a; String b; @override public void mymethod(){dosomethigb;} public void dosomethingelse(){dosomethingelse;}];
```

would work like

```
public A createAClass(){
return new A()
{
   int a; 
   String b; 
   @override public void mymethod()
   {dosomethigb;} 

   public void dosomethingelse()
   {dosomethingelse;}};
};}
```

but if i write in another part of the program

```
createAClass()[float c; List d; public void yourmethod(){dosomething2;} @override public void dosomethingelse(){dosomethingelse2;}];
```

it would instead work like

```
public A createAClass(){
return new A()
{
   float c; 
   List d; 
   public void yourmethod()
   {dosomething2;} 
   @override public void dosomethingelse()
   {dosomethingelse2;}
};}
```

My bad, i choose a bad may of making an example, but i thought it was the clearest way. Maybe i should have used X instead of T?..

Long story short:
i want create an anonymous class inside a method, but define what the anonymous class does in the method caller, and not inside the method(like the title says)

**EDIT2:**
i know i can't access the new methods from the class, what i do now is create an anonymous class, add a few attributes and method, and then use them in an overridden method. The added methods are not a problem, since i can make the method caller to pass an interface that is called by the overridden method in the anonymous class created, the problems are the attributes. I don't know how to add them in the anonymous class passing them from the method caller.

Comment: What is [T]? Is it generic type?

Comment: What you have provided doesn't make a lot of sense because the `[T]` is not valid syntax and we can't tell what you mean by it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following usually works:

```
public A createAClass(final String value){
      return new A(){
         // some code here that can access value
      };
}
```

If you are looking for something else, please clarify the question.

**Edit**

Answer is no you can't do that. You are trying to create an `A` with no defined API for `A`. Even if you could do what you propose, how would any user of `A` know what methods / fields are available if `A` is not defined somewhere? For `A` to be useful, you need to have an API that `A` implements.

Comment: this is not what i want, it is simply creating an anonymous class inside a method. I edited the question, maybe it is more clear now

Comment: @Jhon B happy you understood the question. I edited the question. See EDIT2

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether fully understood by me. But the pattern is like this:

```
public class Here {
    private int stuff;
    public class A {
        private A() { ... }
        ... ++stuff; ...
    }
    public A createA() { ... }
}
...

Here here = ...
A a = here.createA();
```

AFTER QUESTION EDITED:

The simplest way is to override a method:

```
final Object stuff = ...;
A a = new A() {
   @Override
   protected void onSomeEvent() {
       ... stuff.toString();
   }
}
```

Then A can call onSomeEvent.

Comment: this creates a class that creates the class A, and increase the counter stuff each time a new class is instantiated? It's not what i need.. I edited the question, maybe now it is more clear